# c++ - Priority Queue - How does it work internally?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, priority-queue

Say I have this declaration of a priority queue:

```
    struct orderByRewards{

    bool operator() (pair<int,pair<int,int> > a, pair<int, pair<int, int> > b){
        return a.first < b.first;
    }
};

priority_queue<pair<int,pair<int,int> >, vector<pair<int,pair<int,int> > >, orderByRewards> Q;
```

I was wondering if anybody could take their time and explain me how does the compiler interpret the compare class.

- Why do I need to overload the () operator ?
- Also, where's the () operator used in its comparing process ?

It feels a little weird, especially since I am not really comfortable with templates and all OOP concepts.

Why do we need to declare the type of a single object and the container type ?

Comment: This isn't really a question about priority queues. You should rephrase the question in terms of, say, `std::sort` or `std::find_if`. Then there's less noise to keep around.

Comment: The comparer is optional, the default is `less`.  Which is a template derived from std::binary_function().  Which, since it acts like a function, provides the operator() overload.  So you need to as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially asking about function objects (or functors). A function object is one that overloads `operator()`. You can use such an object as though it were a function. The standard provides a few comparison functors (like your `orderByRewards`). For example, `std::less` looks something like this:

```
template <class T>
struct less {
  constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const 
  {
    return lhs < rhs;
  }
};
```

As we can see, the overloaded `operator()` just compares the two arguments using `<` and then returns the boolean result. To use this, you need to create an object of type `std::less` and then use the function call syntax on it:

```
std::less<int> compare;
assert(compare(5, 7) == true);
```

Even though `compare` is an object, we were able to use it like a function in `compare(5, 7)`.

So now we know that your type `orderByRewards` is a function object type. You are passing it as a template type argument of `std::priority_queue`. The implementation of `std::priority_queue` can then create objects of this comparison function object when it needs to compare elements within the queue.

Consider a simpler example:

```
template <typename T, typename Comp>
struct foo {
  void bar(T a, T b) {
    Comp compare;
    if (compare(a, b)) {
      std::cout << "True" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "False" << std::endl;
    }
  }
};
```

It's a silly example, but it gets the point across. We can use this like so:

```
foo<int, std::less<int>> my_foo;
my_foo.bar(5, 7); // Will print true
```

We were able to configure `foo`, by passing it some arbitrary comparison functor type, that its member function `bar` was able to instantiate and use.

So in the same way, you are configuration `std::priority_queue` by giving it a comparison functor type that it can use to order elements within the queue. This is how it determines priority between elements. In fact, the default template type argument for `std::priority_queue` is `std::less`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not required to overfload the operator(). You can declare your custom method:

```
typedef bool (*comp)(int,int);
bool compare(int a, int b)
{
   return (a<b);
}
int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<int,std::vector<int>, comp> pq(compare);
    return 0;
}
```

**Updated**: 
As @WhozCraig pointed out:
It is possible to use this object without overloading the operator() but the compiler will face an easier situation inlining operator() comparison function rather than runtime-provided dereferenced comparison function

Comment: While you can do so, I don't advise it. The compiler has a considerably harder time (if not impossible) inlining the comparator when doing this.

Comment: Because the comparison is through a runtime-provided dereferenced function address as opposed to a compile-time type-directive. Providing comparison through a *type* allows the compiler to throw out the comparison object entirely and effectively inject the comparison function-call operator body directly into the priority queue algorithms (which it will do from any non-brain-dead optimizing C++ compiler).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would make the most sense to look at the definition of `std::priority_queue` and work from there.

```
template <class T, class Container = vector<T>, 
          class Compare = less<typename Container::value_type> >
class priority_queue {
```

This says that `Compare` is some type, and defaults to `std::less<T>`, for T = the value_type of the underlying container. This compensates for the possibility that you might do something slightly insane like creating a priority_queue of one type, but have the underlying container hold another type (though that's not particularly likely, except by accident).

`std::less`, in turn, is defined like this:

```
template <class T> struct less {
    bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;
    // plus a few typedefs for the argument and return types.
};
```

In short, it's a type defined with only one publicly available operation: an `operator()` that can be passed two items that it compares, and returns a `bool` to indicate whether the first is less than the second.

Since that's what `std::priority_queue` expects to use, whatever you provide must support essentially the same function call-like syntax and semantics (e.g., the `operator()` should take `const` arguments and should itself be const-qualified).